# How to make vertical children of flex container to have independent widths

Tags: css, flexbox

I believe this is not possible with flexbox as I have not found the way to do it, but maybe I miss on something.

One parent container has two children containers - one below another.
The width of the second child (`links-container`) grows, once we upload HTML file with links with long text. When it happens, the width of the first child (`form-wrapper`) grows too - as the second child actually makes the whole parent wider and both its children adjust their width. However, I need to keep the width of the first child (`form-wrapper`) as it was before at all times.

I got the effect by using the `display: inline-block` on the child which width I want to keep. But is it possible to do it with flexbox properties?

Here is the code. To see the problem - remove the part `.form-wrapper {display: inline-block;}` from css.

On codepen https://codepen.io/bakrall/pen/rNaZKgq I have the same code but already without the `display: inline-block;` for comaprison. You will see how the width of upload button grows after uploading some html file with links.

```js
(function(){
 function bindUiEvents() {
  $('#file-upload').change( function() { 
   renderLinks(this.files[0]);
  });
 }

 function renderLinks(file) {
  const reader = new FileReader(),
   $linksContainer = $('.links-container');

  reader.onload = function(event) {
   const text = event.target.result,
    pattern = /(<a.+)(<\/a>)/gm,
    links = text.match(pattern);

   $linksContainer.empty();

   links.forEach(link => {
    $linksContainer.append(
     `<li class='link-item'>${link}</li>`
    )
   });
  }

  reader.readAsText(file);
 }

 bindUiEvents();
})();
```

```css
html {
 font-size: 16px;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 height: calc(100vh - 5rem);
 margin: 5rem 0 0;
 background-color: #007da1;
}

h1 {
 padding: 0 0.4rem;
}

.form-wrapper {
 display: inline-block;
}

.link-harvester-form fieldset {
 margin: 0;
 border: 0;
 padding: 0;
 color: #fff;
}

#file-upload {
  border: 0;
  clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0);
  height: 1px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 0;
  position: absolute !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
  width: 1px;
}
 
#file-upload + label {
  background-color: #12312b;
  border-radius: 4rem;
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px #12312b;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
  
#file-upload:focus + label,
#file-upload + label:hover {
    background-color: #06425b;
}
  
#file-upload:focus + label {
  outline: 1px dotted #000;
}

.links-container {
 margin-top: 1.25rem;
 list-style: none;
 padding: 0 0 0 5px;
 font-size: 1.3rem;
}

.links-container a {
 color: #12312b;
 font-weight: bold;
}

.link-item {
 margin: 5px 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="link-harvester-wrapper">
        <div class="form-wrapper">
            <h1>Link Harvester</h1>
            <form class="link-harvester-form">
               <fieldset>
                <input id="file-upload" type="file">
                <label for="file-upload">Upload file</label>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <ul class="links-container"></ul>
    </div>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="js/linkHarvester.js"></script>
</body>
```

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem using the code you provided. Deactivating `display: inline-block` has no effect.

Comment: @Michael_B Thanks for pointing that out. I updated the description as the problem happens when display: inline-block is off and we upload html file with links inside. I will prepare a codepen as it may be more handy.

Answer (score 1):

You can control that with the `flex` property. It takes three parameters, `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink`, and `flex-basis`. Flex basis is the starting width for the element. Flex grow is whether or not the element grows if the container is wider than the sum of the width of the elements. Flex shrink is how much the element will shrink if the container is narrower than the sum of the width of the elements.

So they both have a basis of 200px. The first element has a flex grow value of 0, meaning it will maintain its 200px width. The last element has a flex grow of 1, meaning it will take up the entire width of the parent container. Since it also has a width of 300px, it will expand the container to 300px, then make sure it takes up that width.

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}

.par{
    display: inline-flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    border: solid 3px dodgerblue;
    height: 80vh;
}

.chi{
    border: solid 3px orangered;
    height: 50%;
}

.chi:first-child{
    background: orangered;
    flex: 0 0 200px;
}

.chi:last-child{
    width: 300px;
    flex: 1 0 200px;
}
```

```html
<div class="par">
    <div class="chi"></div>
    <div class="chi"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this example - it is very explanatory, however it does not work when applied to my code. But based on your suggestion I managed to keep the first child width independent, by applying to it `display: inline-flex` and `flex-direction: column`. So yes, finally it is possible with flex.

Comment: In my example `flex-wrap: wrap` does not put the second child under the first, as in your example.

Comment: I know why - I simplified my code as much as I could to mimic yours - but I did not mimic your html completely. In my case my first child has two children. And this is enough to make `flex-wrap: wrap` not work as in your example. Though I do not understand it.